# A way to get compilation error when a method writes to db but parent has @Transactional(readOnly = true)

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I'm using Spring's `@Transactional` to manage my Hibernate transactions. Is there a way to get a compilation error or IDE warning when method X is trying to write to the db but it is being called within method Y who has `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`? This would be tremendously helpful to realize your db write will fail because your top layer method is readOnly when coding.

For example:

```
Class A {
   @Transactional(readOnly = true) 
   public void readFoo(){
       b.writeFoo();
   }
}

Class B {
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)(
   public void writeFoo(){
       userDao.update(user);
   }
}
```

Comment: short answer: no... long answer: you may find an IDE that is able to mark it as a warning for you by underlining it in yellow or something, but it will not fail to compile.

Comment: @ShadowCreeper do you know if IntelliJ IDEA supports this?

Comment: I do not know. You can email their support. They are usually very quick with their responses and you will likely get a human reply by tomorrow (if not today). You could also go into `File`->`Settings`->`Inspections` and search for "annotations" or some such and see what you get.